# how to break the key value and stored in two different variable to use them as parameter(stored_procedure) in ms SQL server in r and shiny

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shinyjs)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(tidyr)
library(shinycustomloader) 
library(tibble)
library(datapasta)

COL = c("#293a80","#39375b","#6915cf","#4b8e8d","#d55252","#293462","#940a37","#f54291","#f0134d","#b22222","#3c4245","#5d1451","#3c3d47")


ui<- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(width=12,
                  withLoader(plotlyOutput("plott1"),type = "html",loader = "loader4"))),
  fluidRow(column(width=12,
                  withLoader(plotlyOutput("plott2"),type = "html",loader = "loader1"))),
  fluidRow(column(width=12,
                  withLoader(plotlyOutput("plott3")))),
  fluidRow(column(width=12,
                  withLoader(plotlyOutput("plott4")))),
  fluidRow(column(width=12,
                  withLoader(plotlyOutput("plott5")))),
  fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("plott6"))
  )

server<- function(input,output)

{
  output$plott1 <- renderPlotly({
    sp1<-tibble::tribble(
      ~DID, ~DistrictName, ~BlockName, ~CenterName, ~TotRaj, ~TotOtherState, ~StateCode,
      76,       "state",     "null",      "null", 7656454,        5645345,     "null"
    )


    ds <- data.frame(labels = c("Rajasthan","Other_State"),
                     values = c(sp1$TotRaj,sp1$TotOtherState)
    )

    plot_ly(ds, labels = ~labels, values = ~values,type = 'pie',source ='listenhere1',
            textposition = 'inside',
            textinfo = 'label+percent',
            insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
            marker = list(colors = c('#5d1451','#745c97'),
                          line = list(color =colors , width = 1)),showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
      layout(
        xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
        yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
  }) 

  output$plott2 <- renderPlotly({
    s <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "listenhere1")
    req(!is.null(s))

    if(s$pointNumber == 0){

      sp2<-tibble::tribble(
        ~DID, ~DistrictName, ~BlockName, ~CenterName, ~TotRaj, ~TotOtherState, ~StateCode,
        101,           "a",     "null",      "null",  564534,         564534,     "null",
        201,           "b",     "null",      "null",  675645,         765645,     "null",
        301,           "c",     "null",      "null",  765645,         786756,     "null",
        401,           "d",     "null",      "null",  987656,         764534,     "null",
        501,           "e",     "null",      "null",  675645,         543423,     "null",
        601,           "f",     "null",      "null",  765434,         231234,     "null",
        701,           "g",     "null",      "null",  564534,         763423,     "null",
        801,           "h",     "null",      "null",  234565,         567876,     "null",
        901,           "i",     "null",      "null",  985646,         876345,     "null",
        102,           "j",     "null",      "null",  876754,         453675,     "null",
        202,           "k",     "null",      "null",  876756,         876754,     "null"
      )

      layout <- list(
        font = list(size = 12),
        title = " District-Wise",
        xaxis = list(title = "district"),
        yaxis = list(title = "records",automargin = TRUE)
      )

      p <- plot_ly(sp2, x = sp2$DistrictName, y = sp2$TotRaj, type = 'bar', name = '',source = 'link3',key = ~paste(sp2$DID, sep = ""),marker = list(color = '#baabda')) %>%
        add_trace(y = sp2$TotOtherState, name = 'Other_State',marker = list(color = '#58508d')) %>%
        layout(yaxis = list(title = ''), barmode = 'stack')
    }
    else {
      sp2<-tibble::tribble(
        ~DID, ~DistrictName, ~BlockName, ~CenterName, ~TotRaj, ~TotOtherState, ~StateCode,
        101,           "a",     "null",      "null",  564534,         564534,     "null",
        201,           "b",     "null",      "null",  675645,         765645,     "null",
        301,           "c",     "null",      "null",  765645,         786756,     "null",
        401,           "d",     "null",      "null",  987656,         764534,     "null",
        501,           "e",     "null",      "null",  675645,         543423,     "null",
        601,           "f",     "null",      "null",  765434,         231234,     "null",
        701,           "g",     "null",      "null",  564534,         763423,     "null",
        801,           "h",     "null",      "null",  234565,         567876,     "null",
        901,           "i",     "null",      "null",  985646,         876345,     "null",
        102,           "j",     "null",      "null",  876754,         453675,     "null",
        202,           "k",     "null",      "null",  876756,         876754,     "null"
      )

      tablename=rowSums(cbind(sp2$TotRaj,sp2$TotOtherState),na.rm=TRUE)

      layout <- list(
        font = list(size = 12),
        title = " Other-State",
        xaxis = list(title = "RECORDS"),
        yaxis = list(title ="STATES" ,automargin = TRUE)
      )

      p <- plot_ly(sp2, colors = COL, marker = list(color = COL),source = 'linkhere',orientation='h',key = ~paste(sp2$DID, sep = "")) %>%
        add_trace( x =sp2$TotOtherState,y = sp2$StateName,name = "states",type = 'bar') %>%
        layout( font = layout$font, title = layout$title, xaxis = layout$xaxis, yaxis = layout$yaxis)
    }
  })

  output$plott3 <- renderPlotly({

    d<-event_data('plotly_click',source = 'link3')
    if(is.null(d)==F){
      sp3<-data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                      DID = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101),
                      DistrictName = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"),
                      BlockName = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh",
                                    "iii", "jjj", "kkk"),
                      CenterName = c("null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null",
                                     "null", "null", "null", "null"),
                      TotRaj = c(564534, 675645, 765645, 987656, 675645, 765434, 564534,
                                 234565, 985646, 876754, 876756),
                      TotOtherState = c(564534, 765645, 786756, 764534, 543423, 231234, 763423,
                                        567876, 876345, 453675, 876754),
                      StateCode = c("null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null",
                                    "null", "null", "null", "null"),
                      CID = c("c01", "c02", "c03", "c04", "c05", "c06", "c07", "c08",
                              "c09", "c10", "c11")
      )

      p <- plot_ly(sp3, x = sp3$BlockName, y = sp3$TotRaj, type = 'bar', name = '',key = ~paste(sp3$DID,sep = ",",sp3$CID), source = 'link1',marker = list(color = '#537ec5')) %>%
        add_trace(y = sp3$TotOtherState, name = 'other-state',marker = list(color = '#57007e')) %>%
        layout(yaxis = list(title = 'sonography block_level'),xaxis = list(title = 'Block name'), barmode = 'group',title='')}
    else{
      return(NULL)
    }

  })

  output$plott4 <- renderPlotly({
    d<-event_data('plotly_click',source = 'link1')
    if(is.null(d)==F){
      sp4<-data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                      DID = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101),
                      DistrictName = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"),
                      BlockName = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa",
                                    "aaa", "aaa", "aaa"),
                      CenterName = c("abc", "bac", "dac", "efc", "ghc", "hic", "jkl", "mnl",
                                     "lkj", "ghj", "kjh"),
                      TotRaj = c(2345, 2343, 6754, 7656, 8767, 6756, 4534, 5678, 6756,
                                 5434, 9876),
                      TotOtherState = c(4532, 2345, 3456, 4567, 9845, 9876, 6756, 5645, 4534,
                                        5645, 7865),
                      StateCode = c("null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null",
                                    "null", "null", "null", "null"),
                      CID = c("c01", "c02", "c03", "c04", "c05", "c06", "c07", "c08",
                              "c09", "c10", "c11")
      )


      p <- plot_ly(sp4, x = sp4$TotRaj, y =sp4$CenterName , type = 'bar', name = 'rajasthan',key = ~paste(sp4$CID, sep = ""),source = "hey",
                   marker = list(color = '#1a3e59',
                                 line = list(color = 'rgba(246, 78, 139, 1.0)'))) %>%
        add_trace(x = sp4$TotFormFOtherState, name = 'other-state',
                  marker = list(color = '#baabda',
                                line = list(color = 'rgba(58, 71, 80, 1.0)'))) %>%
        layout(barmode = 'stack',
               xaxis = list(title = "Centre Data"),
               yaxis = list(title ="Centre Name"))}
    else{return(NULL)}
  })

  output$plott5 <- renderPlotly({
    s <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "linkhere")
    req(!is.null(s))

      sp5<-tibble::tribble(
               ~DID, ~DistrictName, ~BlockName, ~CenterName, ~TotRaj, ~TotOtherState, ~StateCode,   ~CID, ~StateName,
             "null",        "null",     "null",       "nul",   "nul",           4532,          1, "null",    "alpha",
             "null",        "null",     "null",       "nul",   "nul",           2345,          2, "null",     "beta",
             "null",        "null",     "null",       "nul",   "nul",           3456,          3, "null",     "gama",
             "null",        "null",     "null",       "nul",   "nul",           4567,          4, "null",    "theta",
             "null",        "null",     "null",       "nul",   "nul",           9845,          5, "null",      "abn",
             "null",        "null",     "null",       "nul",   "nul",           9876,          6, "null",      "mnb",
             "null",        "null",     "null",       "nul",   "nul",           6756,          7, "null",      "vbg",
             "null",        "null",     "null",       "nul",   "nul",           5645,          8, "null",      "hjg",
             "null",        "null",     "null",       "nul",   "nul",           4534,          9, "null",      "klj",
             "null",        "null",     "null",       "nul",   "nul",           5645,         10, "null",      "ghj",
             "null",        "null",     "null",       "nul",   "nul",           7865,         11, "null",      "jhg"
             )


      layout <- list(
        font = list(size = 12),
        title = " District-Wise",
        xaxis = list(title = "district"),
        yaxis = list(title = "records",automargin = TRUE)
      )

      p <- plot_ly(sp5, x = sp5$StateName, y = sp5$TotOtherState, type = 'bar', name = '',source = 'link3',key = ~paste(sp5$DID, sep = ""),marker = list(color = COL))

  })


  output$plott6<-renderPrint({
    s<-event_data("plotly_click",source = "link1")
    if(length(s)==0)
    {
      "CLICK ON BARCHART TO PRINT THE VALUES!"
    }
    else{
      as.list(s)
    }
  })

}



runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

screenshots to make it understand better...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjRU8.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlS9c.jpg)

i am using the stored procedure from ms SQL server for this purpose but created it the simplest way possible to make it run on other's machines. as shown in the images, how to break the key value into two values and store them in two different variables.how to split and store them.

Comment: You are asking this question for the [second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58742403/how-to-split-the-key-values-into-two-separate-values-and-store-in-distinct-varia) now. To split your key you can use something like `unlist(strsplit("101,c07", split=","))`. However I'd recommend using a unique key and filtering your source data according to the selection instead of passing your custom data via the key.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **minimal** example on how to filter your dataset based on `plotly_click`-events and pass the resulting variables as parameters to a SQL query:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(datasets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("myPlot"),
  tableOutput("myQueryResult"),
  textOutput("myExampleQuery")
)

keyedIris <- iris

# create unique row id
keyedIris$myKey <- 1:nrow(keyedIris)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly(plot_ly(keyedIris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color = ~Species, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", source = "mySource", key = ~myKey))

  filteredIris <- reactive({
    myPlotEvents <- event_data(event = "plotly_click", source = "mySource")
    keyedIris[keyedIris$myKey %in% myPlotEvents$key,]
  })

  output$myQueryResult <- renderTable({
    filteredIris()
    })

  output$myExampleQuery <- renderText({
    sprintf("SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species IN (%s) AND Petal.Length IN (%s) AND Petal.Width IN (%s)", filteredIris()$Species, filteredIris()$Petal.Length, filteredIris()$Petal.Width)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: thanks for your help, i have been looking for this answer for a very long time but in your case, it is passing single key on each plotly_click event, but in my case,wanna pass more than one (might be twice or thrice) on single click event, i mean for single case, i want to pass multiple values, let's say, in SP it will kinda look like this...d<-event_data('plotly_click',source = 'linkhere')
 if(is.null(d)==F){qrydd=paste("exec db_name..[sp_name]",d$key,",'','','','','0','2','15','','01/01/2017','31/12/2017'") and linkhere key would be like this key = ~paste(sp3$DID,sep = ",",sp3$CID)

Comment: i hope, you would understand what i am trying to explain here

Comment: I understood you very well. With the above I wanted to show that you don't need to pass multiple keys. You can always break the problem down to a single key and filter a `data.frame` to provide you with multiple variables for later use. As you can see, in my above example using a single key leads to a query with three parameters.

Comment: okay, i got it, earlier i was looking it from my own perspective that's where i went wrong, first, i need to filter the data, then apply the key concepts to them, i beg your pardon for not understanding the problem very well earlier, thanks for your help though,no one was paying attention to this problem until you came to rescue,thanks again,your helps means a lot to newbie like us to this filed

Comment: No problem, this is what this site is made for. Nevertheless, for your next question I'd encourage you to reduce the amount of code you send and try to condense it to the core - otherwise most people will be deterred by the time they have to spend finding your actual problem and move on.

Comment: one little question though,i have done most of the work with filtering method,but got stuck and figure it out till then working on temporary solution to split the key and store them to two distinct variable,i have done the first part using your method `unlist(strsplit("101,c07", split=","))`,converted it to dynamically like... `output$check<-renderPrint({
  s<-event_data("plotly_click",source = "link10")
  if(length(s)==0)
  {
  return(NULL)
  }
  else{
    # as.list(s)
    m<- unlist(strsplit(s$key, split=","))
    print(m)

  }
})but how to store them in distinct variables.

Comment: `x <- m[1];  y <- m[2]`

Comment: thanks a lot for bearing with me this long on this issue,it worked for me and achieved what i was looking for even beyond my imagination, thanks again for your concern and help throughout this issue